# How can I extract values from two matrices based on the values in one of them?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing

I was wondering what best practices are for the following:

I have two matrices, `a1` (500-by-40) and `a2` (1-by-500). For `a1`, which is boolean, I want to separate out the arrays depending on the values in a particular column (i.e. true or false). I would also need to separate the corresponding entry in `a2`.

I can do this with a couple of loops, or perhaps even by concatenating `a1` and `a2`, doing the logical test and then separating them again, but was wondering if there is a commonly used method for something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a guess, but it sounds like for the true entries in each column in `a1` you want to extract the corresponding values in `a2`. Since you said `a1` is a boolean (known as a [**logical**](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-97022.html) type in MATLAB) you can use [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1) in the following way:

```
vals1 = a2(a1(:,1));  %# Use column 1 of a1 as an index into a2
vals5 = a2(a1(:,5));  %# Use column 5 of a1 as an index into a2
...
```

Here's an example:

```
>> a1 = logical(randi([0 1],10,4))  %# Make a random logical matrix

a1 =

     0     0     1     1
     0     1     0     0
     1     1     1     1
     1     0     1     0
     0     0     1     1
     0     0     1     0
     0     1     1     0
     1     0     0     0
     1     1     0     1
     1     0     0     0

>> a2 = 1:10;
>> a2(a1(:,1))  %# Get the values in a2 corresponding
                %#    to the ones in column 1 of a1

ans =

     3     4     8     9    10

>> a2(a1(:,2))  %# Get the values in a2 corresponding
                %#    to the ones in column 2 of a1

ans =

     2     3     7     9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newval=a1(:,5); %equals to the 5th column
```

Comment: thanks - i tried truevals = a1(:,5) && (a1 == 1) but that doesnt seem to work - id like to extract (the rows) only if the col values are true